# How can I filter on a row in a table in excel without messing up any of the data?

Tags: excel, filter, datatable, data-dump

[Excel Table Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAYV6.png)

I have an excel data dump that is set up funky, but I am needing to filter on a certain row ("Site", in the image) but I need to keep all the other data the same. When I filter on "Site" I want to just show the certain Date's that fit the site and financial information underneath it. For example, I want to get to the point where I can filter on site "a", and it shows the four months "June 2022", "July 2022", "August 2022", and "September 2022" with all the financial information below it. When I try to just do it as a table, or transpose it and turn it into a pivot table it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas I can try? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you try `FILTER()` function?

Comment: Actually I could suggest that to transpose the table first. For the transpose, select all the cells and right-click on empty area and select 'Transpose' for paste step. After that you can use basic filter feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
a a a b b b
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6

=FILTER(A1:F3,A1:F1="a")

a a a 
1 2 3 
1 2 3
```